# Proving $\lim\limits_{n→∞}\int_S^T(g-ϕ_n)^2\,\mathrm dt=0$

Tags: real-analysis

First, define $$t_k=\begin{cases} 
k\cdot2^{-n} & S\leq k\cdot2^{-n} \leq T\\
S & k\cdot2^{-n}<S \\
T & k\cdot2^{-n}>T 
\end{cases}$$
Now suppose $g\in C[S,T]$ where $S,T\geq0$ and define $$\phi_n(t)=\sum_j g(t_j)\chi_{[t_j,t_{j+1}]}(t).$$
Is it true that $$\lim_{n→∞}\int_S^T (g-\phi_n)^2\,\mathrm{d}t=0\text{ ?}$$

Comment: Use uniform continuity of $g$ and the fact that $|t_{k+1}-t_k| \leq \frac 1 {2^{n}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$First, define$$
ψ_n(t) = \sum_{k = [2^n S]}^{[2^n T]} g(t_k) I_{[t_k, t_{k + 1})}(t), \quad n \geqslant 1
$$
then $φ_n(t) - ψ_n(t) = \sum\limits_{k = [2^n S]}^{[2^n T]} g(t_k) I_{\{t_{k + 1}\}}(t)$ implies $φ_n = ψ_n$ almost everywhere and$$
\int_S^T |g - φ_n|^p \,\d t = \int_S^T |g - ψ_n|^p \,\d t. \quad \forall p > 0
$$

Next, because $g \in C([S, T])$, there exists $M > 0$ such that $|g(t)| \leqslant M\ (t \in [S, T])$, then$$
|g(t) - ψ_n(t)| \leqslant |g(t)| + |ψ_n(t)| \leqslant 2M. \quad \forall t \in [S, T]
$$
For any fixed $t \in [S, T]$ and any $n \geqslant 1$, suppose $t \in [t_{n, k}, t_{n, k + 1})$, where$$
t_{n, k} = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{k}{2^n}; & S \leqslant \dfrac{k}{2^n} \leqslant T\\
S; & \dfrac{k}{2^n} < S\\
T; & \dfrac{k}{2^n} > T
\end{cases}.
$$
Note that $|t_{n, k} - t| \leqslant \dfrac{1}{2^n}$, then $t_{n, k} → t\ (n → ∞)$, which implies $ψ_n(t) = g(t_{n, k}) → g(t)$, i.e. $|ψ_n(t) - g(t)| → 0\ (n → ∞)$. Therefore for any $p > 0$, by the dominated convergence theorem,$$
\lim_{n → ∞} \int_S^T |g - φ_n|^p \,\d t = \lim_{n → ∞} \int_S^T |g - ψ_n|^p \,\d t = 0.
$$
Taking $p = 2$ yields$$
\lim_{n → ∞} \int_S^T (g - ψ_n)^2 \,\d t = 0.
$$